# Best practice to add comment to article from article#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the ['Getting Started'](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide of rails

Everything works well, and i read almost all the other chapters. I added a custom validator on the Comment model to exercise a little.
The validator adds and error, and i want to print it in the comments/_form.html.erb partial by using the same code of Article

```
<% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

The validator works well (the transaction rolls back successfully) but nothing is printed in the partial. The @comment is nil.

What is the best way to get the error showed up?

EDIT:

Here is the draft validator

```
    class AntiSpamValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.body.starts_with? 'http://'
      record.errors[:body] << "Pls don't spam!"
    end
  end
end


class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  validates_with AntiSpamValidator
end
```

Comment: Show me your custom validator

Comment: @PhongPhan done

Comment: How did you render form with error `@comment`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [ActiveModel::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)

Here you will find that you need to add the error with a message **about** the body, not append a message into it.

So you could do like this:

```
...
if record.body.starts_with? 'http://'
  record.errors.add(:body, :spam, message: "Pls don't spam!")
end
...
```

---

By the way:

`.full_messages` prepend the localized field name to the error message so you would print something like: `"Body Pls don't spam!`

If you only want to display the message, you could do something like this in the view:

```
<% @comment.errors.each do |field, msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

**But of course this would break default error messages of Rails**